# Verify if WordPress title starts with character

Tags: php, wordpress, substr

I am trying to verify if the WordPress post title starts with certain 3 first characters to achieve a condition. Here is what i tried by it brings back the title itself.

```
$verify = the_title();
if(substr($verify,0,3) == '000'){
$maptitle = 'test 1';
} else {
$maptitle = 'none';}
```

Comment: You code is working as you specified. what do you mean by saying it brings back the title itself?

Comment: You probably need to interact with the `wp_insert_post_data` hook https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

Comment: I mean it echoes the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `get_the_title()`. `the_title()` will print the title to the screen. In your case, you need to return the title so that you can parse it.

`$verify = get_the_title();`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

If you want to use `the_title()`, you can, but you will need to specify that you want the value returned.

`$verify = the_title('', '', false);`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

Comment: Yes this works now. Thank you for your clarification

Comment: sure try to name the page with only one or two '0' and it will show you it starts with 3.

Answer (score 0):

How to apply your filter at edit time using https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

```
function my_wp_insert_post_data_filter( $data )
{
  if( substr( $data['post_title'], 0, 3 ) == '000' )
  {
    $data['post_title'] = 'test 1';
  }
  else
  {
    $data['post_title'] = 'none';
  }
  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'my_wp_insert_post_data_filter' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "exact" comparison because otherwise it will be compared by casting types to 0 or false and it will show you misleading records

change the if to

`if (substr(get_the_title(), 0, 3) === '000') {`

pay attention there are three `=`